# React Native - align text at bottom left of parent view?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Working in React Native here and just trying to align some child text in the bottom left of a View. Ive tried various topMargin and padding options, but none work reliably/responsively.

What I have/want:

[image]

Code currently:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onPress(props.id)}>
      <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text style={styles.card_Head}>What is <Text style={{fontFamily: 'SequelSans-BlackDisp'}}>Something?</Text></Text>
          <Text style={styles.card_Body}>Count: {count}      Id: {props.id}</Text>
      </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>);

card: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        height: wp('79%'),
        width: wp('79%'),
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        color: 'black',
        padding: 40,
        textAlign: 'left',
        borderRadius: 20,
        marginBottom: hp('9%'),
      },
      card_Head: {
        fontFamily: 'SequelSans-RomanDisp',
        fontSize: hp('4.4%'),
        lineHeight: hp('4.4%'),
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
      },
      card_Body: {
        textAlign: 'left',
        fontFamily: 'SequelSans-BlackDisp',
        fontSize: hp('1.5%'),
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',

      },
```

How can I do this responsively?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box `space-between` prop like this

```
card: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'space-between'
}
```

Comment: This works, but the space-between is too much. How can I control how much space there is?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try `align-self: 'flex-end'` like this:

```
card_Body: {
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontFamily: 'SequelSans-BlackDisp',
    fontSize: hp('1.5%'),
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',

  },
```

Or `marginTop` in percentage.